# Need Data Structure in below format using javascript

Tags: javascript

```
let responseData = [
  {
    type: 'element',
    name: 'ns2:VehicleInfo',
    elements: [
      {
        type: 'element',
        name: 'ns2:price',
        elements: [
          {
            type: 'text',
            text: '123',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        type: 'element',
        name: 'ns2:model',
        elements: [
          {
            type: 'text',
            text: 'vento',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        type: 'element',
        name: 'ns2:brand',
        elements: [
          {
            type: 'text',
            text: 'Vw',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        type: 'element',
        name: 'ns2:date',
        elements: [
          {
            type: 'text',
            text: '29 Nov 2022',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        type: 'element',
        name: 'ns2:vin',
        elements: [
          {
            type: 'text',
            text: '1',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    type: 'element',
    name: 'ns2:VehicleInfo',
    elements: [
      {
        type: 'element',
        name: 'ns2:price',
        elements: [
          {
            type: 'text',
            text: '10012',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        type: 'element',
        name: 'ns2:model',
        elements: [
          {
            type: 'text',
            text: '4matic',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        type: 'element',
        name: 'ns2:brand',
        elements: [
          {
            type: 'text',
            text: 'BMW',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        type: 'element',
        name: 'ns2:date',
        elements: [
          {
            type: 'text',
            text: '29 Nov 2022',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        type: 'element',
        name: 'ns2:vin',
        elements: [
          {
            type: 'text',
            text: '2',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

Using JavaScript
above data need to be formatted like

```
let obj = \[
{
id: '1',
vin: '1',
brand: 'Vw',
model: 'vento',
date: '22/11/22',
price: '123',
},
{
id: '2',
vin: '2',
brand: 'BMW',
model: '4matic',
date: '22/11/22',
price: '10012',
},
{
id: '3',
vin: '3',
brand: 'TATA',
model: 'Nano',
date: '22/11/22',
price: '$10000',
},
\];`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `map` with `reduce`

```js
let responseData = [
  {
    type: 'element',
    name: 'ns2:VehicleInfo',
    elements: [
      {
        type: 'element',
        name: 'ns2:price',
        elements: [
          {
            type: 'text',
            text: '123',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        type: 'element',
        name: 'ns2:model',
        elements: [
          {
            type: 'text',
            text: 'vento',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        type: 'element',
        name: 'ns2:brand',
        elements: [
          {
            type: 'text',
            text: 'Vw',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        type: 'element',
        name: 'ns2:date',
        elements: [
          {
            type: 'text',
            text: '29 Nov 2022',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        type: 'element',
        name: 'ns2:vin',
        elements: [
          {
            type: 'text',
            text: '1',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    type: 'element',
    name: 'ns2:VehicleInfo',
    elements: [
      {
        type: 'element',
        name: 'ns2:price',
        elements: [
          {
            type: 'text',
            text: '10012',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        type: 'element',
        name: 'ns2:model',
        elements: [
          {
            type: 'text',
            text: '4matic',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        type: 'element',
        name: 'ns2:brand',
        elements: [
          {
            type: 'text',
            text: 'BMW',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        type: 'element',
        name: 'ns2:date',
        elements: [
          {
            type: 'text',
            text: '29 Nov 2022',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        type: 'element',
        name: 'ns2:vin',
        elements: [
          {
            type: 'text',
            text: '2',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
]

const result =  responseData.map(item => {
    return item.elements.reduce((acc, item) => {
       return {
         ...acc,
         [item.name.replace('ns2:', '')] : item.elements[0].text
       }
    
    }, {})
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

@Sachila Ranawaka's example works fine. If you wanna add the `id`, too like in your preview, so modify the `map` with a second parameter (the index).

```js
let responseData = [
  {
    type: 'element',
    name: 'ns2:VehicleInfo',
    elements: [
      {
        type: 'element',
        name: 'ns2:price',
        elements: [
          {
            type: 'text',
            text: '123',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        type: 'element',
        name: 'ns2:model',
        elements: [
          {
            type: 'text',
            text: 'vento',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        type: 'element',
        name: 'ns2:brand',
        elements: [
          {
            type: 'text',
            text: 'Vw',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        type: 'element',
        name: 'ns2:date',
        elements: [
          {
            type: 'text',
            text: '29 Nov 2022',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        type: 'element',
        name: 'ns2:vin',
        elements: [
          {
            type: 'text',
            text: '1',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    type: 'element',
    name: 'ns2:VehicleInfo',
    elements: [
      {
        type: 'element',
        name: 'ns2:price',
        elements: [
          {
            type: 'text',
            text: '10012',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        type: 'element',
        name: 'ns2:model',
        elements: [
          {
            type: 'text',
            text: '4matic',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        type: 'element',
        name: 'ns2:brand',
        elements: [
          {
            type: 'text',
            text: 'BMW',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        type: 'element',
        name: 'ns2:date',
        elements: [
          {
            type: 'text',
            text: '29 Nov 2022',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        type: 'element',
        name: 'ns2:vin',
        elements: [
          {
            type: 'text',
            text: '2',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
]

const result =  responseData.map((item, index) => {
    return item.elements.reduce((acc, item) => {
       return {
         ...acc,
         id: index+1,
         [item.name.replace('ns2:', '')] : item.elements[0].text
       }
    
    }, {})
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this(as a more readable way I guess) other than the other answers:

```
let obj = responseData.map((element,index)=>{
  const object={};
  object.id=index+1;
  object.vin=element.elements[4].elements[0].text;
  object.brand=element.elements[2].elements[0].text;
  object.model=element.elements[1].elements[0].text;
  object.date=element.elements[3].elements[0].text;
  object.price=element.elements[0].elements[0].text
  return object    
})
```

Comment: Not really scalable unfortunately.